# Firefox: page does not reload if i select the address bar and click enter

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

In my application, i have a page that does not refresh if i select the address bar and click enter. It would refresh if i click on ctrl-R. F5 also does not refresh the page.

What might be the reason?

Comment: Does the address have a `#` in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that this only manifests itself when you've got a fragment identifier (#) at the end of the URL or within it?

For example: www.example.com/pagename#

If you've got fragments within your URL, Firefox won't refresh but will simply try and take you to the location of the ID on the page (and if it's just a trailing hash, then - as Ian pointed out - it will jump to the top of the page, which you won't see if you haven't scrolled at the time).

Just to clarify (and thanks to Ian below for his comment), the reload/doesn't-move really manifests itself when there are *multiple* fragments within the URL.

If it's not multiple hashes, try this:

- load the page
- scroll downwards
- refresh
- see if it jumps to the top of the page (despite not actually reloading the page).

If none of that, perhaps open up console and make sure you've not got a JS error firing when you refresh.

Comment: If it's just a trailing hash, it will take you to the top of the page

Comment: Hi @Ian, you're absolutely correct.  Sorry, I really meant if there were multiple hashes within the URL.  This is what happens when trying to write and eat a sandwich at the same time! I'll update my answer, thank you.

Comment: Haha no problem. It's really a minor detail - the important thing is if there's a hash in the URL **at all**, which you've pointed out :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you have a hash (#) in your URL, it could be the reason for the issue on reloading when clicking enter. Maybe it could seem stupid, but if you have a laptop often the F5 key must be used in combination with FN key. However, telling you the cause just by imagining it's hard, you should link us the page.